# How to include the value of a <input type='button'> in POST request within a Flask app?

Tags: html, forms, post

I am trying to create a login-form in HTML that is supposed to send the values of four inputs with type='button' to a FLASK app backend in a post request, after a button of type='submit' is clicked (relevant code included below). However, all that shows up at the server is an empty ImmutableMultiDict (ImmutableMultiDict([])). I'm wondering why my code isn't working?

When I change the input type to text, the data does suddenly show up serverside. However, it is crucial for my application that the data can be selected in a button.

This is the code for one of the button inputs. I wrapped the form around it for clarity:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('handle_login') }}" method="post" id="login-form">

    <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" 
    name="zwart_voor" value="Naam" data-toggle="dropdown" aria- 
    haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"/>

</form>
```

This is the code for the button that is supposed trigger the POST request:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary login-button" type="submit" form="login-form" value="Submit">Start spel</button>
```

And lastly, this is the relevant Python code of the FLASK app.

```
@app.route('/handle_login', methods=['POST'])
def handle_login():
   print(request.form)

   return render_template('index.html')
```

Again, the print just returns (ImmutableMultiDict([]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A button's name=value pair is only posted to the server if it is used to submit a form. That can only happen if it is `type="submit"` (the default).

Setting `type="button"` indicates that the button has no built-in functionality (i.e. it will only do what JavaScript tells it to do) so it *can't* submit the form.

Change the `type` attribute if you want the button to submit the form.

Use a `<input type="hidden">` if you want to submit data when a form is submitted but not link that data to the clicking of a specific button.