# how do i send submit button value?

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

I have 2 submit buttons I need to retrieve the value of the button but it seems the value does not exist when I click the button btnSubmit, I need the value of it (REJECT or ACCEPT), it returns the undefined value

```
<%
    If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" Then
            dim oConnDbMUDP
            set oConnDbMUDP = server.CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
            oConnDbMUDP.Mode = 3        'allow writable
            oConnDbMUDP.CursorLocation = 3
            oConnDbMUDP.ConnectionTimeout = 600
            oConnDbMUDP.CommandTimeout = 600
            oConnDbMUDP.Open(SESSION("g_strDataConn"))
            dim file
            set file = request.Form("file_name")
            dim approval_value
            set approval_value = request.form("btnSubmit")
     

    if Approval_value = "APPROVE" then

    v_strMsg = "Upload Merchant Telah diapprove dan telah diinsert ke database"

        
    else
     v_strMsg = "Upload Merchant Telah direject dan telah diinsert ke database"

    end if
    
%>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=javascript>
<!-- 

function frmSubmit(){
    document.frmInput.submit();
}
function frmReject() {
    document.frmInput.submit();
}
</SCRIPT>

<form name="frmInput" method="POST">
<table>

    <tr>
        <td >
            <tr class="font10black">
        <td colspan="3" align="right"> 
        <input class="button" type="button" name="btnSubmit" value="BACK" onClick="frmBack()" >
        &nbsp;
      <input style="border:none;background-color:#eeeef0;" readonly="readonly" type="hidden" name="file_name" value="<%=file_name%>">
        <input class="button" type="button" name="btnSubmit" value="REJECT" onClick="frmReject()" >

        <input class="button" type="button" name="btnSubmit" value="APPROVE" onClick="frmSubmit()" >
        &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>

        </td>
    </tr>
    
    
</table>
</form>
```

when i click btn REJECT of APPROVE apparently approval_value retrieve no value from btnSubmit, how do i solve this problem?

Comment: [See this as to why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55513476/1682881). Also, `set` is used when you are assigning objects to variables, it's not needed when a string is assigned. `approval_value = request.form("btnSubmit")`

Comment: This approach is a complete mess. Why do you even need to use use JavaScript to submit the form, both of the functions do the same thing? You only need to use JavaScript to submit a form if you are manipulating a value before submission programmatically.

Comment: As @Flakes said it’s blank because you try to `Set` the string as an object reference.

Comment: the issue is that you are saying input type="button" vs type="submit" if you do type="submit" it should work